# Build and test with TeamCity and Fakes Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, microsoft-fakes

We are running a TeamCity 8.1.4 buildserver with VS2013 installed on the machine.

I've recently introduced tests which rely on the Microsoft Fakes Framework. Because of this I had to add some references to the new Fake assemblies and the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` assembly.
This all runs fine on my local development machine.

Now, when I try to build the solution on the TeamCity server, the following errors are thrown:

> SomeDirectory\Processors\ProcessorTests.cs(3, 27): error CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'Fakes' does not exist in the namespace
>   'SomeDirectory.Database' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> SomeDirectory\Processors\ProcessorTests.cs(7, 66): error CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'Fakes' does not exist in the namespace
>   'SomeDirectory.Service.Processor.Report.Processors' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)
>
> SomeDirectory\Processors\ProcessorTests.cs(9, 17): error CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'QualityTools' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I somewhat understand the first two errors, because I haven't committed the Fake assemblies in SVN, therefore they can't be found. I also don't want to commit these files, because the build server should generate these by itself. The `BuildAction` of the fakes-files is set to `Fakes`.

My guess is the first two errors have their origin met at the third error. To my knowledge the `QualityTools` namespace resides in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` assembly.

I've tried to fix this with several settings.
The original build step I had configured was:

> Runner type = Visual Studio (sln)
>
> Visual Studio = Microsoft Visual
>
> Studio 2013

I've changed this to:

> Runner type = MSBuild
>
> MSBuild version = Microsoft Build Tools 2013
>
> MSBuild ToolsVersion = 12.0

I've also tried the MSBuild version `.NET 4.5` with ToolsVersion `4.0`.

All of these settings result in the same errors.

As you can understand, the solution won't compile at the moment, so I can't tell for sure if the tests will run or not. I've already found [a post](http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/unit-testing-visual-studio-2012-fakes-in-team-city/) on how to configure the test step with TeamCity, but that's the next step.

Anyone got an idea on how to fix these issues with TeamCity and VS2013?

**Edit**

I've already checked if the `TestTools.UnitTesting` assembly exists on the filesystem. This assembly is present, so this shouldn't be a problem

**Edit 2**

Oops, I've misread the third error message. I should have been looking for the `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` assembly, because it says it can't resolve the `QualityTools` namespace. After checking the path `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` I can confirm the dll isn't present on the filesystem.

I've copied it manually to the buildserver and see what will happen next.

**Edit 3**

After having copied the `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` assembly to the build server, the solution compiles like a charm. However, now I'm receiving the familiar

> Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and
>   COR_PROFILER environment variables.

I've seen this before on a TFS2012 server. This meant it wasn't able to handle shims and we had to upgrade to TFS2013.

I just logged in on the buildserver and saw the VS2013 version is expired. That's perhaps the reason it doesn't work properly. The installed VS2012 installation is version 11.0.50727.1, so Update 3 is not installed. I'll discuss with my colleagues if this can be updated. Hopefully this will resolve the issues I'm facing with the fakes and shims.

**Resolved**
Apparently someone thought it was funny to install the VS2013 Professional on the buildserver. Therefore the fakes couldn't run, as it's a Premium feature. Installed the Premium version and everything works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fakes wont run with MSTest you have to you VSTest.Console

Usually (for VS2012 in this case) it is located `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`

There is also runner available on http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/VSTest.Console+Runner, but if this doesnt work, run the executable "by hand", here is reference for running `vstest.console.exe` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx.

If you have VS2013 installed on agent machine (Pro edition contains fakes, express doesn't) it should compile fine. Have you tried clean checkout on your dev machine?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've found this also, as mentioned in the original post. The tutorial I followed for the test step is: http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/unit-testing-visual-studio-2012-fakes-in-team-city/ However, I'm currently having issues with compiling, so I'm not executing the test step, yet.

Comment: Have you tried doing clean checkout and rebuild on your dev machine, maybe some files arent checked in?